# Obscure inequality in a passage of a proof (maximal ergodic theorem)

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, ergodic-theory, proof-explanation

Look at the following excerpt from the book "Einsiedler and Ward- Ergodic Theory, with a view towards Number Theory":

---

[image]

---

I don't understand why  the inequality in the red box is valid. Maybe the explanation is simple, but not for me. Can you help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For each $0\leq n\leq N$ you have $A \geq f_{n+1}$, hence 
$$
  A \geq \max_{0\leq n\leq N}f_{n+1} \geq \max_{1\leq n\leq N+1}f_n \geq \max_{1\leq n\leq N}f_n
$$ 
in particular.

Comment: Many thanks, however I think that the second $\ge$ must be an $=$.

Comment: Well, I was too cautious :) but that's enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are given that $UF_N +f \geq f_{n+1}$ for all $0\leq n\leq N$, hence
$$
  UF_N +f \geq \max_{0\leq n\leq N}f_{n+1} = \max_{1\leq n\leq N+1}f_n \geq \max _{1\leq n\leq N}f_n.
$$